# Flutter BLoC event race condition

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Let's assume we have an app where user has a calendar where he can select a date for which he wants to get list of events. When user selects the date, we add an event `CalendarSelectedDateChanged(DateTime)`. Bloc component fetches data from API each time we receive such an event. We can imagine a situation when the response is received with different delay. This will produce the following scenario:

- User clicks date 1
- API call is made with param date=1
- State is set to loading
- User clicks date 2
- State is set to loading
- Response from request date=2 is received
- State is set to dataLoadSuccess(date=2)

**Expected result is that we discard response from request date=1 here**

- Response from request date=1 is received
- State is set to dataLoadSuccess(date=1)

How can we resolve such a race condition in the most elegant way (preferably for all BLoCs in the app at once)?

Here's an exemplary code that will produce such an issue:

```
class ExampleBloc extends Bloc<ExampleEvent, ExampleState> {

  ExampleBloc()
      : super(ExampleDataLoadInProgress(DateTime.now())) {
    on<ExampleSelectedDateChanged>((event, emit) async {
      await _fetchData(event.date, emit);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _fetchData(DateTime selectedDate,
      Emitter<ExampleState> emit,) async {
    emit(ExampleDataLoadInProgress(selectedDateTime));
    try {
      final data = callAPI(selectedDateTime);
      emit(ExampleDataLoadSuccess(data, selectedDate));
    } on ApiException catch (e) {
      emit(ExampleDataLoadFailure(e, selectedDateTime));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default all events are processed concurrently, you can change that behavior by setting a custom transformer:

You can read more about transformers here: https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_concurrency

```
class ExampleBloc extends Bloc<ExampleEvent, ExampleState> {

  ExampleBloc()
      : super(ExampleDataLoadInProgress(DateTime.now())) {
    on<ExampleSelectedDateChanged>((event, emit) async {
      await _fetchData(event.date, emit);
    },
      transformer: restartable(), // ADD THIS LINE 
    );
  }

  Future<void> _fetchData(DateTime selectedDate,
      Emitter<ExampleState> emit,) async {
    emit(ExampleDataLoadInProgress(selectedDateTime));
    try {
      final data = callAPI(selectedDateTime);
      emit(ExampleDataLoadSuccess(data, selectedDate));
    } on ApiException catch (e) {
      emit(ExampleDataLoadFailure(e, selectedDateTime));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the events processed sequentially before this version?

Comment: If you mean mapEventToState then yes. Here's a question on how to make mapEventToState run in parallel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700401/flutter-how-to-process-bloc-events-in-parallel In short, you cannot await in the mapEventToState but call another async method.